# Crontab error running python script on EC2

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu

Im trying to execute periodically a bash file, that run 3 different python scripts

```
#!/bin/bash
ARCHIVO_PYTHON1="/home/ubuntu/folder/lambda_function.py"
ARCHIVO_PYTHON2="/home/ubuntu/folder/customer_scrapping.py"
ARCHIVO_PYTHON3="/home/ubuntu/folder/ai_analyzer.py"

REGISTRO="/home/ubuntu/folder4/runner_weekly_log.txt"

echo "Ejecutando $ARCHIVO_PYTHON1..." | tee -a $REGISTRO
python3 $ARCHIVO_PYTHON1 2>&1 | tee -a $REGISTRO

echo "Ejecutando $ARCHIVO_PYTHON2..." | tee -a $REGISTRO
python3 $ARCHIVO_PYTHON2 2>&1 | tee -a $REGISTRO

echo "Ejecutando $ARCHIVO_PYTHON3..." | tee -a $REGISTRO
python3 $ARCHIVO_PYTHON23 2>&1 | tee -a $REGISTRO
```

The log seems like it's not taking properly the libraries
But when i run normal this file using the nex command on the terminal:

```
bash starter.sh
```

It work perfectly! The crontab for some reason is working different
I check the /usr/bin/python3 to verify it's working, and it is.

To explain better the problem, let me share a fragment of the code that is getting error:

```
def delete_gsheet(self):
    SCOPES = self.scopes
    creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
            
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            #     'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_config(client_config=CLIENT_CONFIG,scopes=SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_console()
            
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    SPREADSHEET_ID = self.spread_id

    # Get the number of rows in the sheet
    sheet_metadata = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID).execute()
    sheets = sheet_metadata.get('sheets', '')
    sheet_id = sheets[0]['properties']['sheetId']
    total_rows = sheets[0]['properties']['gridProperties']['rowCount']

    # Delete all rows
    requests = [{
        'deleteDimension': {
            'range': {
                'sheetId': sheet_id,
                'dimension': 'ROWS',
                'startIndex': 1,
                'endIndex': total_rows
            }
        }
    }]

    body = {
        'requests': requests
    }
    try:
        response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
        print(f"Deleted {total_rows} rows from the sheet.")
    except:
        print('No hay eliminar')
```

And this is working, but on the crontab log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/folder/gspreads_update.py", line 592, in <module>
    f = financiera_facturas_sheet().insert_data_report()
  File "/home/ubuntu/folder/gspreads_update.py", line 141, in insert_data_report
    self.delete_gsheet()
  File "/home/ubuntu/folder/gspreads_update.py", line 62, in delete_gsheet
    creds = flow.run_console()
AttributeError: 'InstalledAppFlow' object has no attribute 'run_console'
```

So please, do you know how to make crontab work properly?

Thanks, best.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including precise instructions how you install the cronjob.